# How to get the each values in 'Ienumerable <String> Urls' in c# for a multiple value xml file?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, ienumerable

The Xml for the file

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <feed xml:base="http://google.com/en-US/syndicate/"  xmlns:d="http://schemas.google.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.giooglt.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title type="text">Partners</title>
  <id>http://googlre.com/en-US/syndicate/Partners</id>
  <updated>2014-01-16T21:33:20Z</updated>
  <link rel="self" title="Partners" href="Partners" />
  <entry>
  <id>http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/syndicate/Partners('4555')</id>
   <title type="text">M55p; Co</title>
  <summary type="text">
   cccc is a Certified Partner, reseller, and implementer of
  Key industries we work with include:
  •   Financial services
  •   Professional services
  •   Media / publishing


  By focusing on mid-market to enterprise clients,
 </summary>
 <published>2009-07-21T14:23:50-07:00</published>
 <updated>2013-11-22T15:00:46-08:00</updated>
<author>
  <name>google chrome</name>
  <uri>http://google.com/</uri>
  <email>retee@gmail.com</email>
 </author>
 <link rel="edit" title="Partner" href="Partners('4255')" />
 <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Links" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Links" href="Partners('4559')/Links">
  <m:inline>
    <feed>
    <title type="text">Links</title>
    <id>http://google.com/('429')/Links</id>
     <updated>2014-01-16T21:33:20Z</updated>
     <link rel="self" title="Links" href="Partners('4ff')/Links" />
    <entry>
    <id>http://ryryr.com/en-US/syndicate/Links('ufufr')</id>
    <title type="text">
    </title>
    <updated>2014-01-16T21:33:20Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="Link" href="Links('partnerpage')" />
    <category term="google.Commerce.ferrr.Syndicate.V2010_05.Link" sch="" eme="http://schemas.frrr.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
      <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:Type>pgooglrpartnerpage</d:Type>
        <d:Description>google Partner Page</d:Description>
        <d:Url>http://googlgt.com/en-US/PartnerDetails.aspx?PartnerId=42555&amp;wt.mc_id=66ttet</d:Url>
      </m:properties>
       </content>
     </entry>
     <entry>
    <id>http://googlet.com/en-US/syndicate/Links('tpartnerrfipage')</id>
    <title type="text">
    </title>
    <updated>2014-01-19T04:01:49Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="Link" href="Links('pinpointpartnerrfipage')" />
    <category term="google.Commerce.Marketplace.Syndicate.V2010_05.Link" scheme="http://schemas.google.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:Type>tpartnerrfipage</d:Type>
        <d:Description>RFI Page</d:Description>
        <d:Url>http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/RFI.aspx?partnerId=4295719419&amp;wt.mc_id=54545</d:Url>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
     </entry>
    </feed>
   </m:inline>
   </link>
</entry>
  <entry>
    <id>http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/syndicate/Partners('45')</id>
     <title type="text">vfere</title>
   <summary type="text">
  cccc is a Certified Partner, reseller, and implementer of
  Key industries we work with include:
  •   Financial services
  •   Professional services
 •   Media / publishing


  By focusing on mid-market to enterprise clients,
  </summary>
  <published>2009-07-21T14:23:50-07:00</published>
 <updated>2013-11-22T15:00:46-08:00</updated>
  <author>
  <name>google chrome</name>
 <uri>http://google.com/</uri>
  <email>retee@gmail.com</email>
 </author>
   <link rel="edit" title="Partner" href="Partners('4255')" />
   <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Links" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Links" href="Partners('4559')/Links" >
    <m:inline>
   <feed>
     <title type="text">Links</title>
   <id>http://google.com/('429')/Links</id>
   <updated>2014-01-16T21:33:20Z</updated>
   <link rel="self" title="Links" href="Partners('4ff')/Links" />
   <entry>
    <id>http://ryryr.com/en-US/syndicate/Links('ufufr')</id>
    <title type="text">
    </title>
    <updated>2014-01-16T21:33:20Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="Link" href="Links('partnerpage')" />
    <category term="google.Commerce.ferrr.Syndicate.V2010_05.Link" scheme="http://schemas.frrr.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:Type>pgooglrpartnerpage</d:Type>
        <d:Description>google Partner Page</d:Description>
        <d:Url>http://googlgt.com/en-US/PartnerDetails.aspx?PartnerId=42555&amp;wt.mc_id=66ttet</d:Url>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
    </entry>
    <entry>
    <id>http://googlet.com/en-US/syndicate/Links('tpartnerrfipage')</id>
    <title type="text">
    </title>
    <updated>2014-01-19T04:01:49Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="Link" href="Links('pinpointpartnerrfipage')" />
    <category term="google.Commerce.Marketplace.Syndicate.V2010_05.Link" scheme="http://schemas.google.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:Type>tpartnerrfipage</d:Type>
        <d:Description>RFI Page</d:Description>
        <d:Url>http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/RFI.aspx?partnerId=4295719419&amp;wt.m</d:Url>
      </m:properties>
      </content>
      </entry>
    </feed>
   </m:inline>
  </link>
  </entry>
  </feed>
```

I have a piece of code where I want to simply console output the values of each Urls.

```
var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/direct.xml")

var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(reader);

XNamespace atom = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
XNamespace metadata = "http://schemas.giooglt.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata";
XNamespace dataservices = "http://schemas.google.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices";

var result = xmlDoc.Root.Elements(atom + "entry")
    .Select(e => new {
        Title = e.Element(atom + "title").Value,
        Id = e.Element(atom + "id").Value,
        Urls = e.Elements(atom + "link")
            .Where(l => l.Element(metadata + "inline") != null)
            .SelectMany(l => l.Element(metadata + "inline")
                .Element(atom + "feed")
                .Elements(atom + "entry")
                .Select(e1 => e1.Element(atom + "content")
                    .Element(metadata + "properties")
                    .Element(dataservices + "Url").Elements.Select(url => url.Value)))
        });

  foreach (var item in result)
     {
    Debug.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", item.Title, item.Id);
    var urls = System.String.Join(",",item.Urls);
    Debug.WriteLine(urls);

  }
```

Here Urls are of type 'Ienumerable Urls'. How to get the values of every element in Urls.

desired output -

```
M55p; Co,http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/syndicate/Partners('4555'),http://googlgt.com/en-US/PartnerDetails.aspx? PartnerId=42555&amp;wt.mc_id=66ttet
M55p; Co,http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/syndicate/Partners('4555'),http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/RFI.aspx?partnerId=4295719419&amp;wt.mc_id=54545
vfere,http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/syndicate/Partners('45'),http://googlgt.com/en-US/PartnerDetails.aspx?PartnerId=42555&amp;wt.mc_id=66ttet
vfere,http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/syndicate/Partners('45'),http: //pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/RFI.aspx?partnerId=4295719419&amp;wt.m
```

Any help is appreciated.

Actual Output

```
 M55p; Co,http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/syndicate/Partners('4555'),http://googlgt.com/en-US/PartnerDetails.aspx?PartnerId=42555&amp;wt.mc_id=66ttet,System.Linq.Enumerable+<SelectManyIterator>d__14`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,System.String]
 M55p; Co,http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/syndicate/Partners('4555'),http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/RFI.aspx?partnerId=4295719419&amp;wt.mc_id=54545,System.Linq.Enumerable+<SelectManyIterator>d__14`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,System.String] 
 vfere,http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/syndicate/Partners('45'),http://googlgt.com/en-US/PartnerDetails.aspx?PartnerId=42555&amp;wt.mc_id=66ttet, System.Linq.Enumerable+<SelectManyIterator>d__14`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,System.String]
 vfere,http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/syndicate/Partners('45'),http: //pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/RFI.aspx?partnerId=4295719419&amp;wt.mSystem.Linq.Enumerable+<SelectManyIterator>d__14`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,System.String]
```

Comment: What is the actual output?

Comment: posted the actual output for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I see. You want a comma-separated list of the URLs. As you pointed out, your `Urls` property is an IEnumerable of strings, so you need to actually iterate over those strings to build the final string you're looking for.

Try this:

```
var result = xmlDoc.Root.Elements(atom + "entry")
    .Select(e => new {
        Title = e.Element(atom + "title").Value,
        Id = e.Element(atom + "id").Value,
        Urls = e.Elements(atom + "link")
            .Where(l => l.Element(metadata + "inline") != null)
            .SelectMany(l => l.Element(metadata + "inline")
                .Element(atom + "feed")
                .Elements(atom + "entry")
                .Select(e1 => e1.Element(atom + "content")
                    .Element(metadata + "properties")
                    .Element(dataservices + "Url").Value))
        });

foreach(var r in result)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", r.Title, r.Id, String.Join(",", r.Urls));
}
```

Just curious: since you're apparently parsing an ATOM feed, have you looked into packages that will do this for you? https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=atom

Comment: the XML has been posted under the post "How to get the multiple values from xml in C#?" under the same account, unfortunately it is still throwing the same error. I have simply replaced .Value with your above suggested solution, it is still giving the same output. Any help is appreciated. Thank You

Comment: any idea on what should be the solution.

Comment: silly to ask as because I am a novice programmer, where should I place those steps and execute it.I will let you know it it worked or not. Thanks.

Comment: @user3188390 Inside your foreach loop as you have shown in your code will do the trick.

Comment: I have edited my post to include the xml file for reference. Still I am not getting each of the Urls for writing it onto the CSv file.Kindly appreciate your help and effort.

Comment: I should have clarified; you needed to change your query back to the way it was. I have updated my solution.

Comment: It is very funny it is still not getting the value of the Urls, the output I am getting is -                                          M55p; Co,http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/syndicate/Partners('4555')      
vfere,http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/syndicate/Partners('45'), I have used the exact xml file as specified in my post.